# Limit of the Incomplete Beta Function special case

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, limits-without-lhopital, beta-function

Using graphing software of the regularized incomplete beta function I notice that for $I_{x}(a,b)$ where $a = k + 1$ and $b = n - k$. Where $n = Ck$ for $C \in \mathbb{N}$ and $C \geq 2$ we get a step function where $I_{x}(a,b)$ is equal to $0$ for $x < \frac{k}{n}$ and $1$ otherwise. I would like to prove

\begin{equation}
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} I_{x}(k+1,n-k) =\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \int^{x}_{0} t^{k}(1-t)^{n-k-1}dt}{\int^{1}_{0} t^{k}(1-t)^{n-k-1}dt}= 0
\end{equation}
for $x < \frac{k}{n}$

I have tried some asymptotic expansions and approximations of the beta functions and the incomplete beta function such as $B_{x}(a,b) \sim \frac{x^a}{a}(1+\mathcal{O}(x))$ however this yields some very incorrect results (such as values that tend towards infinity when we know the regularized incomplete beta function is bounded between $0$ and $1$ for values of $x$ between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The integral can be written as $I_{x}(k+1,n-k) = \frac{ \int^{\frac{k}{n}}_{0} t^{k}(1-t)^{n-k-1}dt}{\int^{1}_{0} t^{k}(1-t)^{n-k-1}dt}$

Comment: So you like to prove $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{j = k + 1}^n {\binom{n}{j}x^j (1 - x)^{n - j} }  = 0
$$ for $0<x<\frac{k}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, and if possible prove that it goes to $1$ for $x \geq \frac{k}{n}$

Comment: Have you tried [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality)?

Comment: @Gary I haven't, are you referring to this section? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#Confidence_intervals

Comment: @reuns apologies in the comment I wrote x is set to $\frac{k}{n}$ ie the upper interval of the integral in the numerator

Comment: @reuns Sorry just to clarify the issue was with my comment not the question. The question as is, is indeed correct

Comment: Can the downvoters please clarify why my question is being downvoted? I have spent many weeks researching this question and putting in a lot of effort...

Comment: It is up to you to make a readable and meaningful question, not to me. Unclear what is $n$ if it is fixed or not.

Comment: @reuns Apologies, and thank you for your edits. Sometimes when deep in research I forget to make things clearer for others to read. I will adjust. I will make it more clear; $n = Ck$ for integers $C \geq 2$